# How to compare 2 different scripts for efficiency?

Tags: python, bash

I have 2 longer scripts that do that same thing.  Once is a bash script and one is python.

What is the best way in Linux to test which is more efficient?

Would using **time** be best?

Comment: Yes it would be the best.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-to-get-execution-time-of-a-script-effectively

Comment: Use `times` and then compare the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Also, use a loop for better precision:

```
time for i in {1..100}; do bash yourbashscript >/dev/null 2>&1; done
time for i in {1..100}; do python yourpythonscript >/dev/null 2>&1; done
```

Comment: Regarding using a loop, it depends what the code does, really. For example, if the script reads from a file, it will likely be faster after the first time.